# Simple C++ two thread issue (Thread application slower than sequential)

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance

I am trying to add even and odd numbers using CPP threads and the code looks as follows

```
typedef unsigned long long ull;


ull EvenSum = 0;
ull OddSum = 0;

void find_Evensum(ull start, ull end)
{
    for(ull i=start;i<=end;i++)
    {
        if((i&1) == 0)
        {
            EvenSum+=i;
        }
    }

}




void find_Oddsum(ull start, ull end)
{

    for(ull i=start;i<=end;i++)
    {
        if((i&1) == 1)
        {
            OddSum+=i;
        }
    }

}



int main()
{

    ull start = 0;
    ull end = 1900000000;

    auto start_time = high_resolution_clock::now();

#if 0
    thread t1(find_Evensum, start, end);
    thread t2(find_Oddsum, start, end);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

#else
    find_Evensum(start, end);
    find_Oddsum(start, end);
#endif
    auto stop_time = high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop_time - start_time);



    cout<<"Even Sum:"<<EvenSum<<endl;
    cout<<"Odd Sum:"<<OddSum<<endl;

    cout<<"Time taken: "<<(duration.count()/1000000)<<endl;


    return 0;


}
```

The code runs at 5 seconds for sequential code.
The code runs at 6 seconds for Threaded code.Why is the thread application taking more time than sequential??

PC is i5 with 8 cores. I open system monitor on linux and see 2 CPUS 100% usage during thread, but still the execution is slow.

The same code runs at 9 seconds for sequential and
 5 seconds for thread in another system which is correct because threaded code is faster.

Both are linux OS.
Build Command : g++ -std=c++11 -pthread main.cpp

I donot understand why this is happening in one system.

Comment: Why using global instead of regular return value?

Comment: "The code runs at 6 seconds for Threaded code.Which is obviously wrong" - Why do you think that? Threading has overhead. Spawning threads takes time. Synchronization between threads is not free. The OS having to schedule more things has a cost. Cache thrashing by multiple threads may degrade perf.  Etc etc. There has to be enough parallel work available in your problem for the benefit of using threads to overcome the costs. Otherwise using threads is just a net loss.

Comment: Also: make sure you've turned *on* your compilers optimizer (in the command line you show, you have *not*).

Comment: `EvenSum`, `OddSum` are near in memory. I suspect that compiler might have to do extra stuff with possible *cache sharing*.

Comment: @Jesper Juhl This is a basic example in a tutorial from which I am learning Cpp multi-threading. So threaded applications behave differently in different machines is the conclusion?

Comment: Running performance tests without optimizations enabled is pointless, since it is measuring the performance of an executable that was deliberately built to favor ease of debugging over execution efficiency.  Add `-O3` to your command line and measure again.

Answer (score 5):

Your code is suffering from *false sharing*. The two counter variables share the same cache line, so the two threads keep tripping over each other, consistently invalidating the cache line so the core executing the other thread has to reload it.

Prefix the second variable with `alignas(64)` to enforce that it is put on a separate cache line.

Comment: or use local variable to update global variable only once. :)

Comment: @mpoeter Thank you ...This was the issue. Very useful piece of information

Comment: @Jarod42 yes, in general I would also advise to prefer local variables. But in general it is good to understand the concept of false sharing and how to avoid it, because it can also occur on members of a shared data structure.